# Can't see spring batch core source code comments in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-batch

I am facing a problem where my spring batch core classes does not show the comments in the class file. For example, jobexecution.class, no comments could be seen in my eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 0):

are you using maven? Download source for spring-batch 'Maven dependencies' in your project (or manually download jar source and attach to jar class if you aren't using maven)

Comment: nope not using maven. And I did manually download the jar source and attach to jar class. It works previously on kepler. But, for kepler sr1, it doesn't show the comments.

Comment: Check in 'Windows|Preferences|File association' if 'class' or 'class with source' are correctly associated. Also check if source attachment as been recorded from 'Attach source' dialog

Comment: there's only 'class' or 'class without source'. And they are associated with 'class file viewer' as default.